# How to convert V8::Value to binary string?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, v8

I post buffer(nodejs Buffer) in function:

```
Handle<Value> some::encrypt_buf (const Arguments& args) {
    String::AsciiValue abuf(args[0]->ToString());
    cout<<abuf.length()<<endl;
    char *buf=*abuf;
    ...
}
```

and get wrong length if buffer have some chars like \0 in buffer. How to get all binary chars to `abuf` and have correct length()?
maybe exists best way to direct convert V8::Value to char* and length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to do so

```
#include <node_buffer.h>
...
Handle<Value> some::encrypt_buf (const Arguments& args) {
    int len=node::Buffer::Length(args[0]->ToObject());
    char *buf=Node::Buffer::Data(args[0]->ToObject());
    ...
}
```

why no official documentation of this? :-\
[https://www.google.ru/webhp?q=%22node::buffer::data%22+site:nodejs.org](https://www.google.ru/webhp?q=%22node%3a%3abuffer%3a%3adata%22+site%3anodejs.org)